# Package a Django app with generated static files

Tags: python, django, gulp, pip, setuptools

I'm creating a standalone Django app that I want to package up and import into a Django project using pip. However my app contains generated static files - CSS, JS, etc which are generated using Gulp. I want to include these in my app but I'm not sure the best way to do this. I don't want to include the generated files in my version control therefore I figure I have 2 options:

- Run my gulp command to generate the files whenever the python package is installed and include them as part of the python package (I tried overriding the `install` command in `setup.py` but couldn't get it to work)
- Run my gulp command from within my project (however I don't think this will work because the JS/CSS files that gulp requires will be stored inside the `site-packages/` of my installed package)

Has anyone done something similar to this or have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: "I don't want to include the generated files in my version control." - why not? The standard way to do this is to put whatever generated assets your app requires in the app's `static` directory. Otherwise you risk unpredictable/inconsistent generated output for anyone using your app.

Comment: True. I guess I have always been against storing generated files in version control. But I think you're right - the easiest solution would be to generate them and store them in version control and have them included as part of the python package.